# Plotting multiple diagram with long text title in R?

Tags: r, plot

Suppose I split the plot into a 2x2 grid `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`, and I want to put a title for each plots (so 4 plots, 4 different titles). However, my title is really long; for example, `ABCDEFGCDEFGPOLINTDEEGHABCDEFGPOLINTDEEGHGSBJWDNLEBDLJHWEBDYB` (the real title is a combination of names, but I can't put it here due to privacy issue, but it is basically the same as the example). The length of the titles range from 4 to 120 letters. How can I perfectly put in the title? that are readable and not running out of the plot. *I am using the base function `plot` and it will be great to keep using this function rather than `ggplot`.

I tried plotting the title as text `text` rather than title `main` in the `plot`, but the text is running out of the plot. I can manually split the title into lines, but it requires many works and I have many plots. The size of the text is also a problem, some of them are huge because the text is short while some of them is actually unreadable. I want them to be consistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to split the strings at a fixed width into new line in each plot.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
n <- 10
pat <- sprintf("(.{%d})", n)
for(i in seq_along(str1)) plot(0, 0, 
            main = gsub(pat, "\\1\n", str1[i], perl = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
library(stringi)
set.seed(24)
str1 <-  stri_rand_strings(4, 50, '[A-Z]')
```